# Flutter build through command line causes to automatically upgrade dependencies

Tags: flutter, flutter-dependencies

When I try to build my flutter project I noticed something weird. If I try to build it through the options in the images it goes through successfully, however if I try to build through the command line using "flutter pub get", "flutter build release", etc. it automatically tries to resolve dependencies and upgrade them.

[Android Studio build option](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CKgSW.png)

[Android Studio run options, which cause the project to build](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HNtx6.png)

Is there a way to stop the build from automatically try to upgrade the dependencies?

I have tried looking through the settings of Android Studio to see if there was an option selecter there that would set it, but I didn't find anything useful.

Edit: Thank you for the comments for realizing something I forgot to mention. The dependencies that get upgraded are not the ones that I have added to the pubspec.yaml file so I am not sure how to affect them.

[These are some of the dependencies that are upgraded and shown in the terminal.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/W2M4n.png)
[These are the dependencies I have added to the pubspec.yaml file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/46Nz8.png)

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to upgrade your dependencies specified in pubspec.yaml file after you run 'flutter build release', write like below

some_dependency: 1.2.0 and not like some_dependency: ^1.2.0

Comment: Thank you for your comment. I forgot to mention that the dependencies that get upgraded are not the ones that I have added to the pubspec.yaml file so I am not sure how to affect them. I.e one of the dependencies is the " async 2.11.0"